# If click count number JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a demo login form. For the demo, I'd like two things to happen:

1. When the user clicks the login button for the **first time**, an error message appears.
2. When the user clicks the login button for the **second time**, they are directed to another page.

Here's how my code looks so far:

```js
function toggleError() {
    var toggleError = document.querySelector('.message--error');
    toggleError.classList.toggle('error-toggled');
}
```

```css
.message {
  display: none;
}

.error-toggled {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="message message--error">
    <span class="message__text">The login details you entered are incorrect.</span>
</div>

<form onsubmit="toggleError(); return false;" action="/" method="get" class="login__form" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="email" class="srt">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required placeholder="Email" class="input input--border-right">
    <label for="password" class="srt">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required placeholder="Password" class="input">
    <div class="login__actions">
        <button type="submit" class="button">Log In</button>
        <a href="index.html" class="login__anchor">Lost your password?</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Using `onsubmit="toggleError(); return false;"` achieves my first objective of displaying an error message.

How would I extend this function so the user is directed to a page when they click the button for a second time? I'm guessing I would write some type of loop?

Comment: Why a loop? A simple counter variable should do. You increase its value by one in your event handler function - and then based on that current value, you decide what to do ...

Comment: I suggested a loop because my knowledge of JS is limited. Can you please show me an example of using a simple counter variable?

Comment: `var clickCounter = 0;` outside of your function (global variable - those aren't generally considered too "nice", but you can work on improving things later.) `clickCounter++;` first thing in your handler function. And then proceed with if/else to do different things, based on whether the value is 1 or 2 ...

Comment: Instead of a counter, you can use two event handlers and swap them.

Comment:  Thanks folks, this has been a huge help and helped me search for the right terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on first two comments here a possible way:

```
<script>
    var clickCounter=0;
    
    function toggleError() {
        //Increase the value by one
        clickCounter++;
        if (clickCounter == 1) {
           //what ever you want to do
           return false;
        } else if (clickCounter == 2) {
          //You need to change the value again
          ...
          var toggleError = document.querySelector('.message--error');
          toggleError.classList.toggle('error-toggled');
          return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```